# What does "Too few parameters. Expected 1." on MS Access mean?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to update records in my form. It's a restaurant reservation system. Given the Table #, the form can let the user input the Customer ID of the person reserving, the reservation time and date. But when I click on the "update" button in my form, a text box will pop up with this:

[image]

And whatever I put in it, the runtime error "too few parameters. expected 1." pops up. Sometimes a "Reserved Error" will pop up. Could someone help me? It's the last step before I could finally finish this project.

This is my code for updating the record:

```
Private Sub Command8_Click()
On Error GoTo errHandling

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "UPDATE tblReserve SET CustomerID = " & """" & Me.txtCustID & """" & _
", ResDate = " & """" & Me.txtResDate & """" & ", ResTime = " & """" & Me.txtTime &      """" & " WHERE TableNum =" & Me.TableNum

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

DoCmd.Close
Exit Sub
errHandling:
MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

[image]

Screenshot of VBA editor with `Debug.Print strSQL`

Comment: Add a `Debug.Print strSQL` statement after you've constructed your SQL string, then copy it from the Immediate Window ([Crtl-G] in the VBA editor) and update your question (click the "edit" link, above) to show us the SQL you are actually trying to execute.

Comment: Edit your question to show us the revised `Command8_Click()` procedure with the `Debug.Print strSQL` statement in it.

Comment: Okay, well, if executing the SQL statement (`CurrentDb.Execute`) causes an error that gets handled by `errHandling:` then the `Debug.Print` will never get executed, will it? Move the `Debug.Print` statement to immediately follow `strSQL = "UPDATE ..."`.

Comment: `UPDATE tblReserve SET TableNum = D-02, CustomerID = 3, ResDate = '12/23/2013', ResTime = '10:00:00 PM' WHERE TableNum =D-02` this is what appeared in my immediate window after inputting data onto my form.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42746/discussion-between-nutellafella-and-gord-thompson)

Answer (score 2):

As revealed in our [chat][1], the essence of the problem was that [TableNum] is a text field and therefore its value had to be enclosed in quotes:

```
"... WHERE TableNum = '" & Me.TableNum & "'"
```

[1]: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42746/discussion-between-nutellafella-and-gord-thompson)

Comment: Converting to a parameter query would eliminate the need for quoted values.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
strSQL = "UPDATE tblReserve SET CustomerID = " & Me.txtCustID & _
", ResDate = " & "'" & Me.txtResDate & "'" & ", ResTime = " & "'" & Me.txtTime & "'" &  " WHERE TableNum =" & Me.TableNum
```

I am not sure why you have 2 sets of double quotes inside double quotes, I think what you were looking for is single quotes :)

However, there are much better ways to format sql than this. Also this seems like homework, so study up!

Comment: tried it but didn't work. i removed `DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True` and the "enter parameter value" pop-up was gone. but it still won't update.

Comment: Access SQL will accept either  `'` or `"` as a string delimiter. In VBA, `"` characters inside a string delimited by `"` are doubled up, as in `"Gord says ""Hello!"""`.